# Regex and str_remove_all in R - only remove words if multiple conditions are met

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to remove all instances of a country name based on the following conditions:

1. Country name not at beginning of string
2. Country name does not follow 'of '

So if I take a fictional string: 
Australia National **Australia** Bank of Australia

I only want to remove the instance of Australia highlighted in **bold**

I am using str_remove_all to pass a collapsed string of country names to a vector of company names.

```
country <- data.frame(name = c("Australia", "Singapore", "Malaysia")) %>%
mutate(name_regex = paste0("((?<!^)\\b", name, "\\b", "|(?<!of\\s)\\b", name, "\\b)"))

country_remove <- str_c(country$name_regex, collapse = "|")

str_remove_all(x, regex(country_remove, ignore_case = T))
```

```
(?<!^)\bAustralia\b     # select all instances not at beginning
(?<!of\s)\bAustralia\b  # select all instances not following 'of '
```

When I try and combine these together, it ends up just removing everything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code to produce the data frame doesn't work.Could you share your data as a `dput`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew solution is perfect. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build the regex like this:

```
country <- data.frame(name = c("Australia", "Singapore", "Malaysia"))
name_regex <- paste0("\\b(?<!of\\s)(?<!^)(?:", paste(country$name, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
s <- "Australia National Australia Bank of Australia"
str_remove_all(s, regex(name_regex, ignore_case=TRUE))
## => [1] "Australia National  Bank of Australia"
```

The pattern will look like

```
\b(?<!of\s)(?<!^)(?:Australia|Singapore|Malaysia)\b
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/gvRe3N/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!of\s)` - no `of` + whitespace immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `(?<!^)` - no start of string position at the current location is allowed
- `(?:Australia|Singapore|Malaysia)` - any of the alterantives
- `\b` - a word boundary.